# Programmatically run at startup on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, autorun

How do I programmatically set an application bundle on Mac OS X to run when the user logs in?

Basically, the equivalent of the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` registry key in Windows.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add the application to the user's "Login Items" (under System Preferences=>Accounts=[user]) or you can add a [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) agent to the user's `~/Library/LaunchAgents` folder (see `man launchd.plist`). Use `~/Library/LaunchDaemons/` if your app has no user-facing UI. As others point out, launchd gives you a lot of control over when the app starts, what happens if the app quits or crashes, etc. and is most appropriate for "daemon" style apps (with our without UI).

The first option (Login Items) can be manipulated [programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/CustomLogin.html) (link from [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson)).

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on how I could do this with AppleScript? (or C++)

Comment: Apple's [dev docs on the subject](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/CustomLogin.html) describe 3 methods for adding a Login Item, with a code snippet for one and a link to sample code for another.

Comment: an example of plist file and how to add it would be very helpful

Comment: @geotavros see `man launchd.plist` for the official (and up-to-date) documentation of the plist format.

Comment: @BarryWark, I posted it myself. The doc is not so easy to understand, I had to experiment with it.

Comment: @BarryWark link is now broken.

Comment: @BarryWark looks like Login Items API is deprecated now, could you update your answer please

Answer (score 10):

A working example is shown below. It's [based on this post](https://superuser.com/a/229792/43997).

Create file `~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.everydaytasks.plist` with the following contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>my.everydaytasks</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/EverydayTasks.app/Contents/MacOS/EverydayTasks</string>
    </array>
    <key>ProcessType</key>
    <string>Interactive</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

To test you need to run this in terminal

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.everydaytasks.plist
```

To unload

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.everydaytasks.plist
```

For more information, see [launchd.plist man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/5/launchd.plist/) and [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-105327).

A [Shared File List](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW5-SW3) is another way of adding your application to startup using "Login Items". See [this example](https://hoishing.medium.com/adding-login-items-for-macos-7d76458f6495) on how to implement it.

Comment: Suppose that I have a parameter of the .list file as a dynamic value generated in the application install moment. How can I pass/send it?

Answer (score 6):

The "correct" method is to create a LaunchAgent for processes you want to start at login that may have a UI and a LaunchDaemon for those that should be pure background processes.
In your installer drop your plist into the correct folder, either for the user, or all users, or the system. The reason this method is superior is because you can use launchd to control how your process is run including the built-in ability to make sure it keeps running even if it crashes or is killed by the user.

Comment: This isn't a critical application that *must* be kept running, it's just for a convenience option in the preferences dialog. Are you saying it'll keep running the application if users exit it? I don't want that to happen.

Comment: No, I'm saying that's an option when you use LaunchDaemons. You can choose how you want the system to run your application.

Answer (score 4):

Wanted to throw this out here for anyone using Qt / C++. Qt makes it super easy to use plists through the QSettings class. Check out this code snippet from a sample dummy application.

```
void MainWindow::readPlist()
{
    QSettings settings(appPlistPath, QSettings::NativeFormat);
    QVariant value = settings.value("mykey");
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Your Value", value.toString());
}

void MainWindow::addPlistEntry()
{
    QSettings settings(appPlistPath, QSettings::NativeFormat);
    settings.setValue("mykey", "myvalue");
}

void MainWindow::removePlistEntry()
{
    QSettings settings(appPlistPath, QSettings::NativeFormat);
    settings.remove("mykey");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by invoking System Events via `osascript`. This should do the trick:

```swift
struct LaunchAtStartupHelper {
    static var isEnabled: Bool {
        get {
            shell(
                """
                osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get the name of every login item'
                """)
                .contains("MyAppName")
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                shell(
                    """
                    osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to make login item at end with properties {path:"/Applications/MyAppName.app", hidden:true}'
                    """)
            } else {
                shell(
                    """
                    osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to delete login item "MyAppName"'
                    """)
            }
        }
    }
    // from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50035059/1072846
    @discardableResult
    private static func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
        let task = Process()
        let pipe = Pipe()

        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        task.arguments = ["-c", command]
        task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
        task.launch()

        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

        return output
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked fine for me. Though we already needed System Events permissions anyway for our app.