# How to display my app's icon (programmatically) on the top right corner of the Mac OS X menu bar

Tags: macos, menubar, trayicon, nsstatusitem

I know Skype does it - they have a special icon register to there. And then when user click on the icon, a drop down menu will appear...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the docs for [status bar](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/StatusBar/StatusBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000073i) and [NSStatusItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  You can also find tutorials and sample code by googling for NSStatusItem.

Comment: Thanks! Additionally, how the item is "registered" such that it always there even if the machine reboots?

Comment: The status bar item only shows up when your application is running, so you need to get the application to automatically start when the machine boots or when the user logs in.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358410/programmatically-run-at-startup-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

[NSStatusItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is responsible for this.