# Check if some application is defined to run at start up

Tags: c++, macos, startup

I'm writing a C++ code that has to check if some program is defined to run at OS startup.
In Windows it would be implemented by checking if some entry exists in the registry (e.g. in

> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

).

What is the equivalent mechanism of registry on OS X and how can I programmatically check for some entry in it?

References to useful manuals would be also very helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358410/programmatically-run-at-startup-on-mac-os-x this may help