# Add node-webkit app to launch on OS login?

Tags: linux, windows, node.js, macos, node-webkit

I'm creating an app for Mac, Windows, Linux using node-webkit and I want to have the app auto launch on start. 
I have googled ferociously but to no avail. **Does anybody know how to add the app to the "login items" using node-webkit?**

Here is a print screen of where it would go on MAC.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically run at startup on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358410/programmatically-run-at-startup-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: @KevinReilly I've seen that post, but my question is specific to node-webkit and for different platforms (win,mac,linux). There must be a configuration on node-webkit or a way of adding it...

Comment: Originally your question mentioned OSX specifically, but from the looks of it, you may need to do some OS detection and handle each separately.

Comment: There's also some discussion here - https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/1000 that may be related to what you're trying to do.