# Run Executable file from another

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode7

I'm trying to create executable file in swift to run main executable file with arguments i want to do it like this .sh file:

```
dir=$(dirname "$0")
exec "${dir}"/Main "$@"
```

how can i deploy such thing for iOS

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I want to create Swift app to launch another swift app with arguments

Comment: So why are you using shell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run an terminal command in a swift script? (e.g. xcodebuild)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971240/how-do-i-run-an-terminal-command-in-a-swift-script-e-g-xcodebuild)

Comment: @AMomchilov i want code analog to this shell code

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`NSTask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/):

```
func shell(args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}

let appPath = dir + "Main"
shell(appPath, "arg1", "arg2")
```

Comment: I can't use this on iOS, when i compile this, error occures on NSTask()

Comment: Oh yeah, NSTask was removed from iOS. Due to app sandboxing, you can't just execute arbitrary code like this. What are you trying to achievE?

Comment: i've signed & converted .deb file to .ipa to run on non jailbroken iphone, the app i want to run uses shell script above..

Comment: when app is run without that script, it can't resolve device id