# How do you set environment vars for a process?

Tags: process, swift3, environment-variables

Copied from [How do I run an terminal command in a swift script? (e.g. xcodebuild)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971240/how-do-i-run-an-terminal-command-in-a-swift-script-e-g-xcodebuild) :

```
import Foundation

@discardableResult
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}

shell("ls")
shell("xcodebuild", "-workspace", "myApp.xcworkspace")
```

This looks neat. I am just wondering how environment variables like `$PWD` can be set for the process (named `task` here...).

---

I tried the following:

```
import Foundation

@discardableResult
func execCommand(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    process.environment = ["PWD": "/Users"]
    if let env = process.environment {
        print(env["PWD"] ?? "Unknown")
    } else {
        print("Environment not available!")
    }
    process.arguments = args
    process.launch()
    process.waitUntilExit()
    return process.terminationStatus
}


execCommand("pwd")
```

And got these lines printed:

```
/Users
/private/tmp/AppIcon.appiconset
```

Apparently the environment variable has been set, but has no effect on the pwd command at all.

---

Another approach:

```
import Foundation

@discardableResult
func execCommand(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    var environment = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
    environment["PWD"] = "/Users" //optionally set new vars, or overwrite old ones
    process.environment = environment
    if let env = process.environment {
        print(env["PWD"] ?? "Unknown")
    } else {
        print("Environment not available!")
    }
    process.arguments = args
    process.launch()
    process.waitUntilExit()
    return process.terminationStatus
}


execCommand("pwd")
```

Unfortunately same results as before.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/process/1409412-environment

Comment: You shouldn't call a `Process` instance a `task`. `NSTask` has been renamed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just set the [`environment`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/process/1409412-environment) variable of the `Process` to a `[String: String]` containing the variable to value mappings.

```
let process = Process()
// ...
process.environment = ["home": "/Users/foo"]
```

If you want to pass on the current environment, you can do it like so:

```
let process = Process()
// ...
let environment = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
environment["home"] = "/Users/foo" //optionally set new vars, or overwrite old ones
process.environment = environment
```

If you want to set the working directory, that's not dictated by a environment variable, but rather, via the [`currentDirectoryPath` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/process/1413110-currentdirectorypath).

```
let process = Process()
// ...
process.currentDirectoryPath = "/Users"
```

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I will post an example soon.

Comment: @qed The working directory isn't obtained from the env var, it's obtained from `process.currentDirectoryPath`. I'm about to change my answer to be more clear