# Swift + terminal

Tags: swift

I'm looking for a way to run terminal commands from in Swift (macOS). I came accross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971240/how-do-i-run-an-terminal-command-in-a-swift-script-e-g-xcodebuild)  post, but I can't seem to get any of the solutions to work. I am trying to shut down my mac from my app as you can do from terminal (`osascript -e 'tell app "loginwindow" to «event aevtrsdn»'`), but whenever I do it, I get error: Couldn't posix_spawn: error 13.

I am using this code:

```
func shell(launchPath: String, arguments: [String] = []) -> (String? , Int32) {
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = launchPath
        task.arguments = arguments

            let pipe = Pipe()
            task.standardOutput = pipe
            task.standardError = pipe
            task.launch()
            let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
            let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            task.waitUntilExit()
            return (output, task.terminationStatus)
        }
```

and I call it from this:

```
let z = shell(launchPath: "/usr/bin/osascript", arguments: ["-e", "\'tell app \"loginwindow\" to «event aevtrsdn»\'"])
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but you must not enclose the second argument
in single-quotes:

```
let z = shell(launchPath: "/usr/bin/osascript", arguments: ["-e", "tell app \"loginwindow\" to «event aevtrsdn»"])
```

That is only necessary when executing a program from the shell.
`Process` passes the given arguments directly to the spawned executable,
without interpretation by a shell.