# how to create a set of swift files using swift programming

Tags: swift, command-line

is there any way to create swift files programmatically using command line tool
 I have to create a set of files with specific code in it based on the inputs given I have to use swift command line tool to generate swift files 
can anyone help me with your suggestions 
I need the code in swift i have to write a swift command line applications which generates a set of swift files

Comment: Show an example of what you want.

Comment: Read manual for bash command `touch`.

Comment: can we create a swift file with a specific code in it using swift programming

Comment: Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971240/how-do-i-run-an-terminal-command-in-a-swift-script-e-g-xcodebuild

Comment: Or you can set new question or edit this one and ask properly

Answer (score 1):

If you *only* need to create swift file you can try `touch fileName.swift` command.

You can create multiple files by `touch file1.swift file2.swift` or if there is any sequence in file names you can try `touch file{1..5}.swift`.

And then using `echo` command to fill file with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a swift files in command line by doing `touch myFile.swift myFile2.swift myFile3.swift` and then you can add whatever you want in it by doing `echo "some text" > myFile.swift`. You can also append some text in it by doing `echo "some text" >> myFile.swift`