# Mac OS terminal command How to differentiate wlan from ethernet address?

Tags: macos, terminal, ip-address

I'm making a mac os app. I'm trying to get the ethernet and wlan addresses. I know these are `en0` and `en1` addresses but depending on devices, `en0` can be the ethernet or the wlan one. Is there a way to know which one it is?

So far I'm using this which gets me both addresses but don't differentiate them:

```
let task=Process.init()
task.launchPath="/sbin/ifconfig"
task.arguments=["en0"]    //or en1

let pipe=Pipe()
task.standardOutput=pipe
task.launch()

let data=pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
guard let stringResult=String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as NSString? else{wlanFailed();return}
print("en0:", stringResult)
```

---

**EDIT**

So now I'm trying to run this command `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder` which works from my terminal.

But I don't know how to make it work from my Mac app. For example, with this:

```
let task=Process.init()
task.launchPath="/sbin/networksetup"
task.arguments=["-listnetworkserviceorder"]
```

I get:

```
launch path not accessible
```

Comment: You can use this command to get address `ipconfig getifaddr en0`. If you call wrong `en` this command revert `null`

Comment: Yes but i still don't know if it's the ethernet or wlan address.

Comment: I found the command `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder` that print your Hardware Port(wi-fi, Thunderbolt Bridge) and Device(en0, en1, bridge1) . I hope that is what you need.

Comment: Mmm... That might help! Thanks :)

Comment: Working from my terminal but not from the Mac app, getting "launch path not accessible", might be cause it's sandboxed.

Comment: chmod +x script.sh

Comment: @MarieDm Please don't add a solution in your question :) Instead add it as an answer.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @artem-dorodovskiy and @nbari for giving me the command line.

I found how to write it thanks to this [SOF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971240/how-do-i-run-an-terminal-command-in-a-swift-script-e-g-xcodebuild).

```
let task=Process.init()
task.launchPath="/usr/bin/env"
task.arguments=["networksetup", "-listnetworkserviceorder"]
```

Answer (score 1):

These are some commands that help to match the interface with the hardware name:

- `networksetup -listallhardwareports`
- `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder`
- `system_profiler SPNetworkDataType`
- `scutil <<< "list" | grep -i airport`

Comment: It works from my terminal but not from the mac app, i also get "launch path not accessible".