# How to call a simple CURL command during XCUITest

Tags: swift, curl, xcuitest

I need to call the following curl command during XCUITest, and don't need to worry about parameters and response here.

Could anyone please help me give some suggestions/sample here? Will it be easier to put the command into a shell script? Many thanks!

***curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{"membershipId": "111", "approved": "true", "env": "stage"}' http://st.com:8080/abc/sp/auditmember***

Comment: “I need to call the following curl command” Can you explain why? And which? There is a big difference between a UI test and a unit test.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for looking at my question, I'm doing UI test here. many thanks!

Comment: And why would a UI test need to call curl? It should just exercise the app, as is.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971240/how-do-i-run-an-terminal-command-in-a-swift-script-e-g-xcodebuild