# Correctly execute shell commands in Swift 5

Tags: swift, bash, shell, process, nstask

I'm new to swift and tried to follow several different tutorials on the internet to make my App run terminal stuff.

I have a checkbox that should enable (through the terminal command) the charging chime (and of course turn it off when unchecked).

EDIT: 
Updated code, still quite not working:

```
@discardableResult func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/"
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

    return output
}


@IBAction func SoundBox(_ sender: NSButton) {

    if(SoundBox.state == NSControl.StateValue.on){

        self.helloLabel.stringValue = "It's On!"

        shell("say hello")
        //shell("defaults write com.apple.PowerChime ChimeOnAllHardware -bool true; open /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app &")

    }
    else if(SoundBox.state == NSControl.StateValue.off){
        self.helloLabel.stringValue = "It's off!"

        shell("say hello")
        //shell("defaults write com.apple.PowerChime ChimeOnAllHardware -bool false; killall PowerChime")


    }
```

New Console output:

```
  2019-04-12 16:44:54.792282+0200 TerminApp[2985:45592] [General] Couldn't posix_spawn: error 13
2019-04-12 16:44:54.795254+0200 TerminApp[2985:45592] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff42444e45 __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6d07c3c6 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff42444c77 +[NSException raise:format:] + 193
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff446495e9 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:error:] + 4437
    4   TerminApp                           0x000000010000299b $s9TerminApp14ViewControllerC5shellyS2SF + 635
    5   TerminApp                           0x000000010000349e $s9TerminApp14ViewControllerC8SoundBoxyySo8NSButtonCF + 1438
    6   TerminApp                           0x000000010000360c $s9TerminApp14ViewControllerC8SoundBoxyySo8NSButtonCFTo + 60
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff3fcf8e80 -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 312
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff3fd63196 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff3fd630c8 __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 136
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff3fd62fca -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 178
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff3fd8fd4f -[NSButtonCell _sendActionFrom:] + 96
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff3fd618e5 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2375
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff3fd8faa0 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 698
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff3fd60322 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 791
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff3fc3c16f -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 5724
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff3fb729de -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 2295
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff3fb71e9f -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 478
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff3fa116c3 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 331
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff3f9ffee8 -[NSApplication run] + 755
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff3f9ef3f0 NSApplicationMain + 777
    21  TerminApp                           0x000000010000475d main + 13
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6e8a13d5 start + 1
)
```

Comment: my 1st guess would be that's caused because you pass the arguments as 1 element of the array so swift treats it as a single argument. I'm no expert in swift though. Try separating your commands and see if it works

Comment: Have you tried running `open /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app &` as a separate command, and not as part of the arguments of `defaults` as well ?

Comment: If you want to directly call bash commands without using the argument separation like you did, creating a custom function like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50035059/2057091) could be a solution.

Comment: I'm close but something still fails

Comment: If you type `say hello` in Terminal, it works? Did you meant `shell("echo `say hello`")`? Also, might want to do `["-l", "-c", command]`?

Comment: Actually just 'say hello' in the terminal works, but that code doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I do it to start ffmpeg in my app. (`ffmpegTask` is a `Process!` instance, declared as an instance property, and `prefs.input_uri` is a String, coming from user input -It is the URI of an RTSP stream). Hope this helps (the "TemporaryFile" thing is from [Ole Begemann's excellent utility](https://oleb.net/blog/2018/03/temp-file-helper/)):

```
/* ################################################################## */
/**
 This starts the ffmpeg task.

 - returns: True, if the task launched successfully.
 */
func startFFMpeg() -> Bool {
    ffmpegTask = Process()

    // First, we make sure that we got a Process. It's a conditional init.
    if let ffmpegTask = ffmpegTask {
        // Next, set up a tempdir for the stream files.
        if let tmp = try? TemporaryFile(creatingTempDirectoryForFilename: "stream.m3u8") {
            outputTmpFile = tmp

            // Fetch the executable path from the bundle. We have our copy of ffmpeg in there with the app.
            if var executablePath = (Bundle.main.executablePath as NSString?)?.deletingLastPathComponent {
                executablePath += "/ffmpeg"
                ffmpegTask.launchPath = executablePath
                ffmpegTask.arguments = [
                    "-i", prefs.input_uri,
                    "-sc_threshold", "0",
                    "-f", "hls",
                    "-hls_flags", "delete_segments",
                    "-hls_time", "4",
                    outputTmpFile?.fileURL.path ?? ""
                ]

                #if DEBUG
                    if let args = ffmpegTask.arguments, 1 < args.count {
                        let path = ([executablePath] + args).joined(separator: " ")
                            print("\n----\n\(String(describing: path))")
                    }
                #endif

                // Launch the task
                ffmpegTask.launch()

                #if DEBUG
                    print("\n----\n")
                #endif

                return ffmpegTask.isRunning
            }
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Sandboxing is likely to be an issue, depending on where you are calling. ffmpeg doesn't like sandboxes anyway, but I still embed the variant that I build for my app in the same directory as the main app executable.