# How to run and print zsh commands in Swift Executables (like "vi")

Tags: swift, command-line-interface, zsh

I need to run commands that require dynamic output in my CLI made in Swift. I've tried things like [ShellOut](https://github.com/JohnSundell/ShellOut) and [other suggestions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971240/how-do-i-run-an-terminal-command-in-a-swift-script-e-g-xcodebuild), but they print the output once the command is done, not while it is going.

What I'm hoping for is something like `system("vi README.md")` from C++, where it will run the command and print the outputs as it goes.

Without it, `vi` prints `Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal` then leaves a black screen and there is no way to exit the command.

Comment: I don't know Swift, but I would assume the solution is actually independent of any particular shell. For example, in Python you would write `subprocess.run(["vi", "README.md"])`, with `vi` being executed directly, rather than starting a shell to execute `vi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, you can use the `system()` function for C++ in Swift!

First, I created a new target in my package (to get past language mixing errors):

```
.target(name: "CBridge", dependencies: []),
```

Then, in the target's source folder, I put the following files:

```
CBridge.cpp
include/CBridge.h
include/CBridge-Bridging-Header.h
```

CBridge.cpp

```
#include "include/CBridge.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void shellCMD(const char *cmd) {
    system(cmd);
}
```

CBridge.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void shellCMD(const char *cmd);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

CBridge-Bridging-Header.h

```
#include "CBridge.h"
```

Simply call `shellCMD(command)` and it will run it, just like 'system(command)'!