# Best approach to obtain current user's groups in Swift for macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

What is the best approach to obtaining the current user's groups in Swift for macOS?

I have come across NSUserName() for obtaining the current user's username, but based on searching and finding absolutely nothing online, I'm under the impression that such a function doesn't exist in regards to user groups.

I'm assuming I will have to leverage something outside of Swift. If that is the case, any suggestions on what I should be leveraging?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/getgrouplist.3.html ?

Comment: What makes one approach the best among all others?  And who decides?

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort you could run a terminal command from swift and read the output. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971240/how-do-i-run-a-terminal-command-in-a-swift-script-e-g-xcodebuild)

And to get the user group have a [look at this](https://superuser.com/questions/590683/how-do-i-find-my-user-id-and-group-in-mac-os-x)

```
import Foundation

func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    let pipe = Pipe()
    
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]
    task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
    task.launch()
    
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    
    return output
}

// Example usage:
shell("id")
```

Output of 'id':

> uid=534(galuga) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff)