# Run script and add files to Swift Package via BuildToolPlugin

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

**Context**
I recently took over a Swift project which relies on git submodules. One of my first task was to clean up the project, which means removing submodules, using Swift Packages.

On my way doing this i encounter a tricky submodule. It contains swift files and a WebPack project that's loaded in a WebView. Currently the project that imports this submodule has a custom build phase that runs `npm ci` + `npm build` to build the WebPack and copy the files into the app.

---

**Question:**
When i switch to using a Swift Package it should manage this custom build phase on its own. Is it possible to run `npm ci` + `npm build` in a `BuildToolPlugin`?

My current state is trying to run a shell script which simply creates a file:

```swift
@main
struct TSPlugin: BuildToolPlugin {

    func createBuildCommands(context: PackagePlugin.PluginContext, target: PackagePlugin.Target) async throws -> [PackagePlugin.Command] {
        let tsPath = context.pluginWorkDirectory
                .appending (subpath: target.name)
                .appending (subpath: "Seatmap")
        print(tsPath)
        print("here1")
        let scriptPath = context.package.directory.appending(["..", "TSPlugin", "TEst.sh"])

        print("here2")
        return [
            .prebuildCommand(
                displayName: "Generating localized strings from source files",
                executable: scriptPath,
                arguments: [],
                outputFilesDirectory: tsPath
            )
        ]
    }
}
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "come on"
touch easypeasy.txt
```

I rebuilt this in a demo project: https://github.com/Deitsch/SwiftPluginDemo

Comment: I guess you can that script!! Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50035059/6630644